# Storing daily statistics in relational database

Tags: database, statistics, relational-database

I'm creating a game that needs to save each players' statistics (games played, exp & gold gained, current gold) on a daily basis, as well as the all-time statistics.

My current approach is I have 3 tables:

```
table `stats_current` -> for storing player's stats on CURRENT DAY
player_id | games_played | gold_earned | current_gold

table `stats_all_time` -> player's stats accumulated from the very beginning
player_id | games_played | gold_earned | current_gold

table `stats_history` -> player's stats daily, one record for one day
player_id | date | games_played | gold_earned | current_gold
```

Each player has one record on `stats_current`, one record on `stats_all_time`, and limited records on `stats_history` table (for example, only last 30 days are recorded).

Then there's a daemon / cron job that do these operation on a daily basis:

- For each players:
- Search for its record on `stats_current`, get the values.
- Insert new record to `stats_history`, values are from `stats_current`
- Update record on `stats_all_time`, increment its values with values from `stats_current`
- On `stats_current`, reset the values of `games_played`, `gold_earned` to 0. But leave the `current_gold` as it is.

Solutions for common tasks:

- **Get player X's current gold:** retrieve `current_gold` from `stats_current`
- **Get player X's stats in last 7 days:** select 6 records from `stats_history`, plus the today's record in `stats_current`
- **Get player X's total games played:** retrieve values from `stats_history`

---

**Questions:**

- Is this a viable approach?
- What are the weaknesses?
- Is there any way to optimize this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach fails to take advantage of the power of SQL

stats_history
To get today's stats, just use

```
SELECT * FROM stats_history WHERE Date = CURDATE() and PlayerId = PlayerId--Depending on your RDBMS you might need a different function to get the date.
```

To get all time stats just use

```
SELECT SUM(games_played) as games_played, SUM(gold_earned) as gold_earned FROM stats_history WHERE PlayerId = playerid
```

You could just pull current gold by selecting the top record from stats_history for that player, or by using any of a number of other RMDBS specific strategies (Over clause for SQL Server, Ordering the result set by date and adding current_gold for MySQL etc.)

Your approach is risky because if your Chron ever fails, the other two tables will be inaccurate. It's also uneccessary duplication of data.